# Join to another table only matching specific records

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of ports:

```
drop table if exists ports;
create table ports(id int, name char(20));

insert into ports (id, name ) values
  (1, 'Port hedland'), 
  (2, 'Kwinana');
```

And a table of tariffs connected to those ports:

```
drop table if exists tariffs;
create table tariffs(id int, portId int, price decimal(12,2), expiry bigint(11));

insert into tariffs (id, portId, price, expiry ) values
    (1, 2, 11.00, 1648408400), 
    (2, 2, 12.00, 1648508400), 
    (3, 2, 13.00, 1648594800), 
    (4, 2, 14.00, 1651273200),
    (5, 2, 15.00, 2250000000 );

insert into tariffs (id, portId, price, expiry ) values
    (1, 1, 21.00, 1648408400), 
    (2, 1, 22.00, 1648508400), 
    (3, 1, 23.00, 1648594800), 
    (4, 1, 24.00, 1651273200),
    (5, 1, 25.00, 2250000000 );
```

Each tariff has an expiry.

I can easily make a query to figure out the right tariff for as specific date for each port. For example at timestamp `1648594700` the right tariff is:

```
SELECT * FROM tariffs 
WHERE 1648594700 < expiry AND portId = 2
ORDER BY expiry
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
id  portId  price   expiry
3   2   13.00   1648594800
```

However, in my application I want to be able to pull in the right tariff starting from the `ports` record.

For *one* record, I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM ports 
LEFT JOIN tariffs on tariffs.portId = ports.id 
WHERE 1648594700 < tariffs.expiry AND ports.id = 2
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
id  name    id  portId  price   expiry
2   Kwinana 3   2   13.00   1648594800
```

This feels a little 'dirty', especially because I am doing a lookup on a record, and then forcing only one result using LIMIT. But, OK.

What I cannot do, and can't work out how to do, is a query that will return a *list* of ports, and *each* port having a `price` field that matches the constraint above (that is, the record with the highest `expiry` compared to `1648594700` for each port).

This obviously won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM ports 
left join tariffs on tariffs.portId = ports.id
where 1648594700 < tariffs.expiry
```

Since the result of the query, testing with timestamp `1648594700`, would be:

```
id  name    id  portId  price   expiry
2   Kwinana 3   2   13.00   1648594800
2   Kwinana 4   2   14.00   1651273200
2   Kwinana 5   2   15.00   2250000000
1   Port he 3   1   23.00   1648594800
1   Port he 4   1   24.00   1651273200
1   Port he 5   1   25.00   2250000000
```

Instead, the result for all ports (before further filtering) should be:

```
id  name    id  portId  price   expiry
2   Kwinana 3   2   13.00   1648594800
1   Port he 3   1   23.00   1648594800
```

Is there a clean, non-hacky way to have such a result?
As an added constraint, is this possible for this to be done in ONE query, without temp tables etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the lowest expiry, do your join and only take the rows having this minimum expiry:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, t.id, t.portId, t.price, t.expiry
FROM ports p 
LEFT JOIN tariffs t ON p.id = t.portId
WHERE expiry = (SELECT MIN(expiry) FROM tariffs WHERE 1648594700 < expiry)
ORDER BY p.id;
```

This will get your desired result, please see here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd3e323dad8589310eca3ac0accf2855)

Comment: Oh my. Just like that. This solves a problem that was so huge for me, it's hard to explain. Thank you very much, this is the neatest I've seen in a while

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, `ROW_NUMBER` should work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.id, p.name, t.price, t.expiry,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY t.expiry) rn
    FROM ports p
    LEFT JOIN tariffs t ON t.portId = p.id
    WHERE t.expiry > 1648594700
)

SELECT id, name, price, expiry
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

This logic would return one record for each port having the nearest expiry.